# How to assign each kubernetes pod to a local ip

Tags: linux, kubernetes, k3s

I want each pod to run on a separate ip(lan/local) as I scale it. (scaling minecraft server network). They might already do this as I see no port conflicts in the containers but I can't tell what ip they are assigned to. I am using k8s btw.

Comment: What do you mean by "run on a separate ip(lan/local)"? Do you want to share host network with pods or just be sure that all pods are in the same network and have access to them from your host?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your query is CNI in kubernetes as it does the magic of networking in your cluster ranging from subnet ip to traffic communication.
Kubernetes is all about sharing machines between applications. Typically, sharing machines requires ensuring that two applications do not try to use the same ports. Coordinating ports across multiple developers is very difficult to do at scale and exposes users to cluster-level issues outside of their control.

Have a read through the [K8's networking model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Kubernetes services to assign IP address to the container. It is an abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service.

There are three types of Services -

1. ClusterIP -This is default.  Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster.
2. LoadBalancer - Services are exposed externally & I guess this is what you may need.
3. NodePort - Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.

Here is an example using LoadBalancer & Cluster IP -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  clusterIP: 10.0.171.239
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.0.2.127
```

[More details can be found here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)